# Angular 2 save unchanged version of a list

Tags: angular

I'm subscribing to an API call using the following code:

```
this.af.database.list("URL")
    .subscribe((lineList) => {
      this.lineList = lineList;
      this.fullLineList = lineList;
});
```

Whenever I access `this.lineList` in my component, `this.fullLineList` changes too.

How I can store a variable which stores `lineList` and is note affected by `this.lineList` changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `slice()` you can create a copy of the list:

```ts
this.af.database.list("URL")
.subscribe((lineList) => {
      this.lineList = lineList;
      this.fullLineList = lineList.slice();
});
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice